# Problem running Hive on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I downloaded the latest Hive release 0.7.1.

> Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME must be set or hadoop
>   must be in the path

I went into this directory /home/hadoop/hive-0.7.1-bin/bin
and tried running the Hive Shell.

./hive shell But I am getting the above error in the CLI.

I tried setting the path:
$HADOOP_HOME=home/hadoop/hadoop/bin

I am using Hadoop 0.20.2

Answer (score 5):

As per the link : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop

Hadoop home is HADOOP_HOME is the parent directory of the bin directory that holds the Hadoop scripts.

Also the following `$HADOOP_HOME=home/hadoop/hadoop/bin` seems to be a relative path. It is better to give the full path from root.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your path not being absolute, the syntax is wrong. Use `HADOOP_HOME=` not `$HADOOP_HOME=`

Answer (score 0):

You should setup environmental variable to your operating system, also hadoop home path should be "hadoop_0.20.2" directory not "bin".

For example in Ubuntu

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/path/to/hadoop/"
```

to check :

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to set this for each time you log on.

First you have to determine your path to hadoop/bin

From your post my guess is it might be

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin
```

Now you can do

```
EXPORT HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin
```

but this would need to be done every time you log on and off.

So I recommend going and adding this file to your profile folder. Usually found in /etc/profile. So try

```
sudo vi /etc/profile
```

and add the following line right on the top.

```
EXPORT HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin
```

Save and quit

```
:wq
```

And then run the following commmand to update your variables

```
source /etc/profile
```

To confirm it works try the following. Notice when using echo you use $ but when assigning the variable you do not.

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

Comment: can you confirm that your hadoop bin is actually at 
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin?

Answer (score 0):

Sample: export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop